# How to deploy fronted angular with backend maven application on aws ec2

Tags: java, linux, angular, maven

I am actually deploying front-end angular with back-end maven application on aws ec2. what is best practice to deploy on ec2. front end angular is isolate from backend maven application.is there any best practices to deploy it and what is configuration required to set it up.and in which directory I should deploy both front end and back end application.

Comment: Have you tried Jenkins and docker before?

Comment: Guess you'll have to install some sort of java application server for your maven build and a web server for the angular app. Haven't read it, but something like [this](https://aws.amazon.com/de/answers/web-applications/aws-web-app-deployment-java/) might help you?

Comment: my war file and front is different build is not binded in single war